# Why can't I edit DevExpress pivot table data?

Tags: c#, wpf, postgresql, devexpress, pivot-table

I need to edit the information displayed in my pivot table, but the component don't let me do it. I'm binding the pivot table to a `DataTable` object, filled from database (PostgreSQL) using Npgsql. 
This is the line that fills the `DataSource`:

```
PivotGridControl1.DataSource = connection.getDataFromQuery("select * from fact");
```

The method `getDataFromQuery` returns a DataTable with the result of query execution.
Then i define the regions of my pivot table:

```
PivotGridField rowName = new PivotGridField ("item", FieldArea.RowArea);
PivotGridField columnField = new PivotGridField("name", FieldArea.ColumnArea);
PivotGridField dataField = new PivotGridField("amount", FieldArea.DataArea);
```

And finally add them to the control:

```
PivotGridControl1.Fields.AddRange(new[] { rowName, columnField, dataField });
```

Thing is that I'm getting the pivot table as I wanted, but I can't edit the data inside the grid.

[image]

I'm using DevExpress 13.2 version, little old, maybe I need to update, or maybe I need to configure something in the component. Any idea?

Comment: DevExpress doesn't have much support for PivotTable. Pretty much the ONLY thing you can do for the PivotTable is to set the data source. And then the DevExpress PivotTable will re-calculate everything afterwards. If I remember correctly, the datasource of the PivotTable is not even a dependencyProperty.  I can imagine changing even a cell would require refreshing the who DataSource again.

Comment: Hi @cscmh99, thing is that in documentation says that you can simply edit any cell, i'm trying that and i can't edit, but maybe is refering to a newer version? Please check [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#InterfaceElementsWin/CustomDocument8457)

Comment: A cell in a pivot table is an aggregation of data, for example sum of orders. Updating a value has no meaning since you can not propagate the update on aggregated data. Use a gridview to update underlying tables

Comment: @HubertL That's a good point. But why documentation say that [this](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#InterfaceElementsWin/CustomDocument8457) is possible?I'm very confused now

Comment: You're right, this is very confusing... maybe if aggregation operator is max or min or if there is no aggregation. You may post a ticket, I've always found DevExpress support very prompt to reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default data in `PivotGridControl` cannot be edited, but you can specify the editor for cell by changing the [`PivotGridField.CellTemplate`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfPivotGridPivotGridField_CellTemplatetopic) property or the [`PivotGridControl.FieldCellTemplate`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfPivotGridPivotGridControl_FieldCellTemplatetopic) property.
For example:

```
<dxpg:PivotGridControl.FieldCellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <dxe:PopupCalcEdit
            EditValue="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}"
            ...
        />
    </DataTemplate>
</dxpg:PivotGridControl.FieldCellTemplate>
```

But you must consider, how the edited value in your editor will be reflected in your underlying data source, because values in `PivotGridControl` are aggregates, not the data itself.
Here is example:

```
<dxpg:PivotGridControl.FieldCellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <dxe:PopupCalcEdit
            EditMode="InplaceInactive"
            EditValue="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}"
            MouseDown="PopupCalcEdit_MouseDown"
            LostFocus="PopupCalcEdit_LostFocus"
        />
    </DataTemplate>
</dxpg:PivotGridControl.FieldCellTemplate>
```

```
private void PopupCalcEdit_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var calcEdit = sender as PopupCalcEdit;

    if (calcEdit == null)
        return;

    calcEdit.EditMode = EditMode.InplaceActive;
}

private void PopupCalcEdit_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var calcEdit = sender as PopupCalcEdit;

    if (calcEdit == null && calcEdit.EditMode != EditMode.InplaceActive)
        return;

    var cellsArea = calcEdit.DataContext as CellsAreaItem;

    if (cellsArea == null)
        return;

    var dataTable = (DataTable)PivotGridControl.DataSource;

    var drillSource = PivotGridControl.CreateDrillDownDataSource(cellsArea.ColumnIndex, cellsArea.RowIndex);

    if (drillSource.RowCount > 0)
    {
        int id = (int)drillSource.GetValue(0, "ID"); //Change only the first row in drilled rows.

        dataTable.Rows.Find(id)["amount"] = calcEdit.EditValue;
    }
    else
    {
        var cellInfo = PivotGridControl.GetCellInfo(cellsArea.ColumnIndex, cellsArea.RowIndex);

        object itemValue = cellInfo.GetFieldValue(PivotGridControl.Fields["item"]);
        object nameValue = cellInfo.GetFieldValue(PivotGridControl.Fields["name"]);

        var row = dataTable.NewRow();
        row["item"] = itemValue;
        row["name"] = nameValue;
        row["amount"] = calcEdit.EditValue;

        dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    calcEdit.EditMode = EditMode.InplaceInactive;

    PivotGridControl.ReloadData();
}
```

Also, take a look at [this](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q324491) DevExpress Support Center thread.

Comment: Thanks man, you definitly solve my problem. The link has a very good sample too.